# Struts2 and Spring integration thread safe

Tags: spring, struts2

We are using Struts2-Spring integration and all my action classes implement SessionAware, sample code to action class and their spring definition is given below,

```
public class IRXxxxAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
  private Map session;

  public String execute()
  {//}

  public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session)
  {
    this.session = session;
  }
}
```

**Spring Configuration**

```
<bean name="userAction" class="com.IRXxxxAction" >
    <property name="adminDAO" ref="adminDAO" />
</bean>
```

If I understand correctly, each auto-wired property will be a singleton, so if the above is true, is there anyway that the session map get shared between two simultaneous requests?

Regards,

Ayush

Comment: And, as a best-practice, `extends ActionSupport and implements SessionAware` (with session Map and its accessors) in a "CoolTechieBaseAction", then extends it from every Action you have, to reduce the redundancy and code written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have asked same question on the user mailing list and as said if you are using Struts2-Spring plugin make sure to put bean scope as `prototype`.

Struts2 create new instance of action on each request, since action work as a model also and in order to make it thread safe a new object is being created on each request and placed on value stack.

Not proving scope will be treated by Spring as `singleton` and for ever request same action instance will be given back which can leads to a lot of issue from data corruption to weird behavior.

Comment: Yes i had asked the question to be posted, since my mails to the mailing group are not going through.

Comment: @CoolTechie Yes, they are; both Umesh and I replied to them.

Comment: Oh if I had a nickel for every time someone had this question... :)